# How to use e-sata external port to access a sata drive

Tags: data-recovery

I have laptop with an external e-sata/USB combo port. I have an internal Seagate SATA drive removed from another laptop. I want to recover the data in this disc. Is it possible to connec t this hardisk through the e-SATA port? If so, what cable would I need to connect in?

Comment: I am glad you were able to get an answer, but also be aware this question is not programming related. This WOULD be a great type of question for superuser.com though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a SATA-to-eSATA cable for the data.  It's pretty standard.  It's getting power to the drive that can sometimes be a challenge.

Alternatively, get an external enclosure, or a SATA-compatible dock.  I use [this](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16817707171) one, and have had no troubles with it.